# bmGlyph how to target font for iPhone 6s Plus for Swift (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, sprite-kit

I'm using bmGlyph app to create custom fonts/labels in a game.

I was publishing the fonts with sd & @2x target. Everything was going fine.
But when I tested using the Simulator on an iPhone 6s Plus, I see that the texts with the custom fonts were missing.

So I thought I would need to create the @3x target for the Plus. 
After testing it, i saw that the fonts were all messed up.

This is how it looks:

[image: bmGlyph text in iPhone 6S Plus]

So, it looks like for iPhone 6S Plus, I might not need to target @3x but other one?

Can anyone help me to understand it? The documentation in the bmGlyph blog is so short.

Thanks.

Comment: From the looks of the picture,  it looks like it is loading your @3x font at 3x dimensions, causing the overlapping

Comment: Mmmmm so if the font is 50px, then it's doing 50x3 = 150px and thats why? When i check at the xml that bmGlyph creates, it says that is doing it to 50px.. its weird.

Comment: I never used bmglyph

Comment: Oh, yea and the documentation is pathetic. I don't know why i actually bought that software ... it was recommended by some user and after i tested it it looked okay but the page itself is outdated, no support, and lame documentation :(

Comment: what does it do? does it make the bitmap font for you?

Comment: wait.... bmGlyph just turns font to a bitmap,  how do you render the bitmap?

Comment: exactly.. you set the "targets" i.e: ipad 4x, iphones 2x, 3x.. creates all the bitmap and then you create the BMGlyphFont and BMGlyphLabel within Swift. The guy who created the software also created (or got helped) to do the Swift support.

Comment: from the looks of it, it does have \@3x support,  do you have the \@1x files  (file name does not have \@1x)

Comment: Yea, basically if it doesn't have any target, it will be the 1x images. (I think)

Comment: Do you have all 3 files

Comment: Mmmm looks like only includes de 2X and 3X images, not the normal ones

Comment: Make a normal one at the 1x dimensions. It should work after that

Comment: Kk let me check :)

Comment: Wait, you suggest like creating only a \@1x ?? not the others? but if they don't have the correct prefix, they won't be displayed in different resolutions.

Comment: No for retina to work. You need all 3 files,  apple used the 1x for point dimensions

Comment: So make a font, font@2x, and font@3x.

Comment: Yea, now i got all 3 but still happens, this is weird. I got 32.png, 32@2x.png and 32@3x.png

Comment: How do you load it

Comment: If you want we can continue on chat so i can give you code snippets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118489/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-msqar).